# Найти среднюю цену каждого товара по магазину. SQL

Tags: sql

Есть 3 таблицы с данными, нужно Найти среднюю цену каждого товара (itemid) по магазину (Shop) М1.

Помогите составить запрос SQL (извиняюсь за вид таблиц, не понял как прикрепить файл):

```
JournalID     Date        Shop (магазин)  TotalQty (кол-во)   TotalAmount (сумма)
1           01.01.2011        М1                55                500
2           02.01.2011        М1                45                450
3           01.01.2011        М4                30                300
```

Lines (Строки журнала продаж):

```
JournalID   Itemid (товар)  Qty (кол-во)    Amount (сумма)
    1           1                 10          100
    1           6                 15          300
    1           8                 20          100
    2           1                 30          300
    2           6                 5           100
    2           8                 10          50
    3           1                 10          100
    3           6                 10          200
```

Goods (Справочник номенклатур):

```
Itemid (товар)  itemname
    1             Рис
    5            Пшено
    7             Соль
    6             Сода
    8             Масло
```

Comment: А где то, что ВЫ пытались сделать? А в чём именно возникла проблема? Сервис "а сделайте мне" находится где-то в другом месте... PS. Да и показанные данные - не только избыточные, но и не согласованные...

Comment: где код?) код в студию)

Answer (score 1):

Оформлено непонятно...
По идеи что-то вроде этого:

```
select item_id, avg(price) as avg_price
from (select item_id, amount/qty as price from Lines) calc_price
group by item_id
```